# Is this function complex differentiable at $3\pi i$?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis

I'm going through old exams and I came across this exercise. I am uncertain if my solution is correct.

---

Is $f(z)=\sin(\bar z +z)$ differentiable at $3\pi i$?

---

We have $f(z)=\sin(2 \cdot \Re(z))$, so $f(x+iy)=\sin(2x)$. According to the Cauchy Riemann equalities, for differentiability, we need:

$$u_x = 2 \cdot \cos(2x) = v_y = 0$$ $$u_y = 0 = -v_x = -0$$

So $\cos(2x)=0$, hence $x = \frac{2k+1}4 \pi$ for some $k \in \mathbb Z$. Since for our given point, $3 \pi i$, we have a trivial real part, we see that the answer is "no".

---

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're basically right, but it's written perhaps a little confusingly.

I would instead say that at $z = 3 \pi i$, we have $u_x = \cos (2x) = \cos 0 = 1$ but $v_y = 0$ and hence $f$ does not satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations at this point.

You kind of took the roundabout route of finding the points where $f$ *is* differentiable, and showing that $3 \pi i$ isn't in that set, which leads to the same conclusion (and is maybe useful if there's a second part to the question which specifically asks for that set).